# Issue using nth-child

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm new at web programming and start reading how we can use properly selector in css. I really need this because I'm developing a blog and my goal is target several paragraphs in a range the more efficient way!

To simplify the problem I made an example, `li`, and I need help to select the most efficient way `li` from [5-15] and why!. Before I post this I read this [article](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/)

```
<ol>
 <li>item one</li>
 <li>item two</li>
 <li>item three</li>
 <li>item four</li>
(...)
<ol>
```

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rm596/PCL7Z/)

Comment: is the number of li's varying

Comment: What did you try? Did you google it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try

```
li:nth-child(n+5):nth-child(-n+15) {
    color: red;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fyB88/)

Comment: I tried to do the same thing with `:not`, but that's really elegant. )

Comment: Totally didn't occur to me that you could stack two nth-childs together to do it.  +1 friend.

Comment: Could you provide an explanation? Your answer is currently incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Using your [example](http://jsfiddle.net/PCL7Z/7/):

```
li, li:nth-child(n+15)~li {
    /* Your normal li style */
}
li:nth-child(n+5) { 
    /* The 5-15 style */ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jquery, you could try this one.

```
var my_selection = [];
for(var i=4;i<=14;i++){
my_selection.push($('ol li').get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arun P Johny's answer is awesome and I'd definitely go with that. If you needed to do the same thing in jQuery due to browser support or something you could use jQuery's [`.slice`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/).

```
$('li').slice(4, 15).css('color', 'red');
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PCL7Z/13/

Answer (score 0):

First if you want a range selector you need to combine something using ',' or ':' like:

```
li:nth-child(), li:nth-last-child() or li:nth-child():nth-child()
```

If the first number in range are 5 you can use this (n+5) why?

| n |  result(n+5)

| 0 |  5 (0+5)

| 1 |  6 (1+5)

| 2 |  7

| 3 |  8

The second part is :(-n+15), why because in last range you only need 15 above. I use simple way